# Upper case field name in json object to angular application

Tags: angular, spring, spring-mvc

i am having spring application with angular JS UI.in my application, i am returning pojo object as JSON to the UI. when returning to UI, pojo fields first letter will be changed to Upper case.For example, parameter "name" is changed to "Name" in json object.But its expecting "name".Due to this we are not able to map the fields in UI component.Could you please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

good afternoon

I think the solution may be the following, make a pipe to put all the data that comes from your service in lowercase example ->

Name:

In lowercase:

```
'{{value | lowercase}}'
```

In uppercase:

```
'{{value | uppercase}}'
```

url: https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: Thanks for your repsponse. Is there any way to do with Spring framwork like appingJackson2HttpMessageConverter

Comment: I do not understand your question, explain me better and I can help you remember to rate me

Answer (score 0):

Solution : In my application, the below property was set. thats y i am getting first letter as camel case ""